# PowerShell Write-Output vs variable dumping in a piping operation

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have a function that converts a PSObject into a hashtable. Function works well, but there's a little subtlety that I am trying to understand and can't really grasp my head around.

I'm using PowerShell Core 7.0.3

The function:

```
function Convert-PSObjectToHashtable
{
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject
    )

    process
    {
        if ($null -eq $InputObject) { return $null }

        if ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and $InputObject -isnot [string])
        {
            $collection = @(
                foreach ($object in $InputObject) { Convert-PSObjectToHashtable $object }
            )

            # buggy
            #Write-Output -NoEnumerate $collection
            
            # correct
            $collection
        }
        elseif ($InputObject -is [psobject])
        {
            $hash = @{}

            foreach ($property in $InputObject.PSObject.Properties)
            {
                $hash[$property.Name] = Convert-PSObjectToHashtable $property.Value
            }

            $hash
        }
        else
        {
            $InputObject
        }
    }
}
```

I execute the following code:

```
$obj = "{level1: ['e','f']}"
$x = $obj | ConvertFrom-Json | Convert-PSObjectToHashtable
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeObject($x)
```

The "buggy" code returns me:

```
{"level1":{"CliXml":"<Objs Version=\"1.1.0.1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04\">\r\n  <Obj RefId=\"0\">\r\n    <TN RefId=\"0\">\r\n      <T>System.Object[]</T>\r\n      <T>System.Array</T>\r\n      <T>System.Object</T>\r\n    </TN>\r\n    <LST>\r\n      <S>e</S>\r\n      <S>f</S>\r\n    </LST>\r\n  </Obj>\r\n</Objs>"}}
```

The correct code returns me:

```
{"level1":["e","f"]}
```

Why wouldn't the buggy code work, if technically, in PowerShell when working with the object result, they look equivalent?

Thank you!

Comment: The difference is `-noenumerate`. Using a variable as output unrolls the array. So each array element is sent to the pipeline. When `-noenumerate` is used, the array as a single object is sent to the pipeline. If you remove `-noenumerate`, then `write-output` will work the same as the variable.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I actually just tried removing `-NoEmumerate` and leaving `Write-Output $collection` and I get the same "buggy" output.

Comment: As an aside: To test if a given object is a _custom_ object ("property bag"), you must use `-is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` - `-is [psobject]` does _not_ work reliably, and neither does `-is [pscustomobject]`, because - confusingly - `[psobject]` and `[pscustomobject]` both refer to `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]`, and incidentally `PSObject`-wrapped objects of any type, as explained in Mathias' answer, therefore also report `$true` for `-is [psobject]` - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11921

Comment: @AdminOfThings: In this particular case - because the command output is assigned to a property and `$collection` is `[object[]]`-typed - `$collection` (letting the engine enumerate and collect in a new `[object[]]` array), `Write-Output $collection` (ditto) and `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $collection` (output the array as a whole) all happen to have the same effect - _except_ that use of a cmdlet, such as `Write-Output` here, creates normally invisible `[psobject]` wrappers, which happen to surface in the `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeObject()` call, as explained in Mathias' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because PowerShell loves to [wrap things in `PSObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803345/preventing-powershell-from-wrapping-value-types-in-psobjects)'s.

The "plumbing" through which `Write-Output` (and all other binary cmdlets) emit standard output is implemented in a way that forces this explicit wrapping of the input objects in a `PSObject`.

So from a PowerShell user's perspective, these two variables have identical values:

```
$a = 1..3 |Write-Output
$b = 1..3
```

By any reasonable indication, both variables hold an array containing the integers 1,2,3:

```
PS ~> $a.GetType().Name
Object[]
PS ~> $b.GetType().Name
Object[]
PS ~> $a[0] -is [int]
True
PS ~> $a[0] -eq $b[0]
True
```

Behind the scenes though, the object hierarchy actually looks like this:

```
$a = 1..3 |Write-Output
# Behaves like: @(1,2,3)
# Is actually:  @([psobject]::new(1),[psobject]::new(2),[psobject]::(3))

$b = 1..3
# Behaves like: @(1,2,3)
# Is actually : @(1,2,3)
```

You might think this would pose a problem, but PowerShell goes through great length to keep this wrapper layer completely hidden from the user. When the runtime subsequently evaluates a statement like `$a[1]` and finds a `PSObject` wrapper, it transparently returns the base value (e.g. `2`) as if it was the actual value referenced by the underlying array.

But `[JsonConvert]::SerializeObject()` isn't written in PowerShell, and when it starts traversing the object hierarchy *outside the confines of the PowerShell language engine*, it encounters the wrapping `PSObject` instances and picks its default serialization format (`CliXml`) instead of what should have otherwise been treated as native JSON types.

The expression `$collection` on the other hand is *not* a binary cmdlet and there are no downstream pipeline consumers, so its value is enumerated and written directly to the output stream, bypassing the `PSObject` wrapping/boxing step. The resulting array therefore references the output values *directly* instead of their respective `PSObject` wrappers, and the serialization works as expected again.

---

You can unwrap objects by referencing the `ImmediateBaseObject` property on the hidden `psobject` memberset:

```
$a = 1,2 |Write-Output
# Actual: @([psobject]::new(1),[psobject]::new(2))

$a = $a |ForEach-Object { $_.psobject.ImmediateBaseObject }
# Actual: @(1,2)
```

Beware that wrapping re-occurs every time an object goes through `|`:

```
$a = 1,2
# Actual: @(1,2)

$a = $a |ForEach-Object { $_ }
# Actual: @([psobject]::new(1),[psobject]::new(2))
```

If you wonder whether an expression returns `PSObject`-wrapped objects from within PowerShell, pass the output to `Type.GetTypeArray()`:

```
PS ~> [type]::GetTypeArray(@(1..3|Write-Output)).Name
PSObject
PSObject
PSObject
PS ~> [type]::GetTypeArray(@(1..3)).Name
Int32
Int32
Int32
```

Comment: Nicely done; the relevant GitHub issue with a list of real-world ramifications is at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579 (I've just added the case at hand to it).To test a single object or a collection itself, you can use `-is [psobject]`. Any reason you're recommending `.ImmediateBaseObject` over `.BaseObject`? Note that applying either to a `[pscustomobject]` instance yields `$null`.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the link, was having trouble finding it last night! I'm using `ImmediateBaseObject` because I was trying to obtain a reference to _the immediate base object_ ^_^ but you have a point, using `BaseObject` is probably a safer lesson to impart on future readers.